Does testRigor have the ability to test with incognito browser, I cannot find anything in the documentation regarding this?
Im am trying to test logging into Gmail and its verification processes. I would like to check this with an incognito or private browser!
Does anyone have any idea on how execute this function along with the Authentication process?
I tried using the command "open new incognito window" hoping that the AI will catch this but was not successful

By default, all tests run in incognito mode. You can turn it on or off from the Settings >> Advanced tab. Under "Desktop Web Fine-Tuning," incognito mode is checked by default.

This was helpful thank you!
